# Angular js validation function returns before the api call for validation is completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

```
                if (!validate()) {
                    return;
                };


            function validate() {
                var nameIsValid = false;
                var validationStatus = true;
                dataApi.GetNameValid(viewModel.Name).then(function (data) {
                    nameIsValid = data.isValid;
                    validationStatus = checkValidInput(nameIsValid);
                });
                return validationStatus;
            }

            function checkValidInput(isValid)
            {
                if(!isValid){
                    return false;
                }
            //chk other input field validations
            }
```

The issue is that validate() always returns true.If I change validationStatus = false then it always returns false.  The GetNameValid is async false still return validationStatus is called before the GetNameValid() completes execution so checkValidInput never gets called and actual validation never happens.
                Is there another approach for this kind of scenarios where you need to wait for the ajax call before the function returns.
Any article or blog pointing in right direction will help.
thanks

Comment: `return dataApi.GetNameValid` and return validation status from the then block.. Chain through it and set a property on the scope/controller instance or what ever you are doing with it `validate().then(function(validity){$scope.valid = validity})`

Comment: @PSL I tried this but it still didn't work the behavior was similar..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you can do is chain together another then onto the one you already have there and that would do what you want. Granted this is untested but I think it should work.

```
if (!validate()) {
    return;
}


function validate() {
    var nameIsValid = false;
    var validationStatus = true;
    dataApi.GetNameValid(viewModel.Name)
    .then(function (data) {
        nameIsValid = data.isValid;
        validationStatus = checkValidInput(nameIsValid);
    }).then(function(validationStatus){
        return validationStatus;
    });
}

function checkValidInput(isValid) {
    if(!isValid) {
        return false;
    }
}
```